# findIndex method is not retrieving the index while the value exist

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to find the index of an object in an array.

```
        for (let i = 0; i < sitesDeTir.length; i++) {
            let affIndex = affectations.findIndex((aff) => aff.id_sdt === sitesDeTir[i].id);
            if (affIndex === -1) {
                // action
            } else {
                // action
            }
        }
```

When I use the Chrome debugger, I can see that sitesDeTir[i].id is equal to 371 (number).
I've also digged in the array (called affectations) and I see that there is an object who have id_sdt to 371 (number) but I always receive -1.

What I'm a missing here?
I'm sorry for the link, I don't have enough reputation to embed it in the post.

[image]

Comment: There is no affectation property called `id_sdt`, only `id_SDT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs because you compare apples with bananas :-) Write `id_SDT` instead `id_sdt`.

```js
 for (let i = 0; i < sitesDeTir.length; i++) {
    let affIndex = affectations.findIndex((aff) => aff.id_SDT === sitesDeTir[i].id);
    if (affIndex === -1) {
        // action
    } else {
        // action
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is in my interface I've declared id_sdt and not id_SDT so I don't know from where id_SDT is coming from..
Therefore, when I do aff.id_SDT I receive the following error -> "Property 'id_SDT' does not exist on type 'Affectation'. Did you mean 'id_sdt'?"

Comment: Ok I got it, It's because the field from my API is 'id_SDT' :-) Thx